# Finding the match from list of dataframes. Implementation of Stupid Backoff algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, list, algorithm, dataframe

I was trying to implement a Stupid Backoff Algorithm in my NGram model. It is basically a recursive function and explained in one of the StackOverflow answers,

```
So for "a sunny day" where no instance was observed, you would calculate S("day" | "a sunny"). Not finding the trigram "a sunny day" you would take case two in equation 5, and estimate S("day" | "a sunny") as alpha * S("day" | "sunny").

If again, you recorded no observances of "sunny day" you would approximate S("day" | "sunny") as alpha * S("day"), which is the terminal case f("day") / N (the number of observed unigrams).

By setting alpha to 0.4 you get exactly what you wrote out above.
```

I tried to implement it by using this function and for now it is working properly. In the code below, wordlist is the list of all the words in corpus, allgrams is a list of all unigrams, bigrams and so on up to n grams. And Uniquegram is the list of all the grams from allgrams but unique ones (not repeating).

```
def probability(n,gram,wordlist,uniquegrams,allgrams):

    if len(gram)==1:
        return (wordlist.count(gram[0])/len(wordlist)) 

    elif gram in uniquegrams:

        ngram_probability = uniquegrams.count(gram) / allgrams.count(gram[:-1])
        return ngram_probability 
    else:
        return probability(n-1,gram[1:],wordlist,uniquegrams,allgrams)*0.4
```

But here I am finding the probability individually. In one of my other functions I have already found all probability and converted them in a list of data frame. For instance,

```
[          0         1
0    sample  0.142857
1         a  0.142857
2      this  0.285714
3        is  0.285714
4  sentence  0.142857,           0         1    2
0        is         a  0.5
1    sample  sentence  1.0
2         a    sample  1.0
3      this        is  1.0
4  sentence      this  1.0,           0         1         2    3
0        is         a    sample  1.0
1      this        is         a  0.5
2  sentence      this        is  1.0
3    sample  sentence      this  1.0
4         a    sample  sentence  1.0]
```

Now I want to use this output in finding the probability of given NGram, for example ["this","is","sample"] is given input, then my function will look for an exact match for it in a list of dataframe shown above. If it is in it, then the function will give the respective probability. If it is not in list of dataframe, it will find the probability for ["is","sample"] and multiply it's probability with 0.4, again if it's not in list of dataframe, it will look for ["sample"] and multiply it's probability with 0.4*0.4.

Please suggest me how can I implement this.

I appreciate all suggestions. I checked some of the answers but still not able to implement it.

Thanks,
Aditya.